# Could not set multiple cookies in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set multiple cookie in NGINX, but there is no proper solution for that.Can any one help me out to fix that. My code is below:

`if ($query_string ~ ([^&]*)cookie=([^&^:]*)){
add_header Set-Cookie "cookieName=test; Domain=.test.com; Max-Age=31536000;path=/";
}`

This cookie should set if the request url has query parameter `cookie=somevalue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($arg_cookie = somevalue){
    add_header Set-Cookie "name=value;max-age=3153600000;path=/";
}
```

Comment: How to set multiple cookies inside the same `if` block?